PostgreSQL Table Size Increased After Aborted VACUUM FULL—Unable to Reclaim Space
I am using PostgreSQL deployed in a Kubernetes cluster, and I connect to it using pgAdmin via port forwarding. I recently ran the maintenance toolkit in pgAdmin on my Prefect database. During this process, I initiated a VACUUM FULL operation on my log table, but I had to terminate the process midway.
After the termination, I noticed that the size of the log table ballooned from 1.5 GB to 7.3 GB. I then tried to delete older rows (more than 7 days old) using a DELETE statement, followed by another VACUUM FULL operation, but the table did not release the additional space.
**Steps I Followed:
**
Ran VACUUM FULL on the log table and terminated it midway.
Observed that the table size increased from 1.5 GB to 7.3 GB.
Deleted rows older than 7 days from the log table.
Tried running VACUUM FULL again, but the space was not reclaimed.
**Current Situation:
**
The log table still occupies 7.3 GB of space even after attempting VACUUM FULL again.
I am looking for a solution to reclaim the disk space that was increased due to the interrupted VACUUM FULL process.
**Environment Details:
**

PostgreSQL is running in a Kubernetes cluster as a StatefulSet.
Connected to the database using pgAdmin with port forwarding.
Prefect is the primary application using the PostgreSQL database.

Questions:

How can I reclaim the disk space from the log table?
Are there any potential risks or alternative methods to recover space safely in this scenario?


Don't use VACUUM FULL. Second, install pg_repack. Third, use table partitioning to drop complete table partitions to simplify maintenance. But you got that answer already in a previous question.

How are you determining the size of the table?
